# Why are there no blinking red lights in slave mode with one of my Yongnuo flashes?

Tags: flash, troubleshooting, yongnuo

I recently bought two Yongnuo 568 EX IIs and they're working great! I'm just having one problem in one of the two: when I put the flash in any of the slave modes (Sc, Sn, S1 or S2), the red lights do not blink on it like it does on my other flash. However, the flash is functioning perfectly as a slave, it is just that no red lights blink on it. If it makes any difference, I'm using them with a Canon 600D.

Is the lack of lights a symptom of a problem I'm not aware of, and is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: I don't know why, but it sounds like a plus to me. If you learn how to turn the blinking off in slave modes, let us know how.  I put a small piece of tape over mine then.  I think your only concern should be if when on the hot shoe, if the AF Assist light works then?

Comment: FWIW, the hot shoe AF Assist light can be turned off in YN-565EX with Function 04, but it does not turn off the blinking in slave modes.

Comment: @WayneF The AF Assist light works fine! It is just the blinking that does not happen in slave mode. As I see it, the blinking lights are just indicators and nothing more than that.

Comment: Anyone found how to turn off the blinking?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a setting to turn on and off the blinking light. As on my YN600EX-RT I am able to turn it on and off on the setting.

On the YN600ex-RT;
Hold the 'ZM/C.FN' button for around 5 sec,
then nivigate to 'SL IND' via the wheel and click set to turn on and off.

Comment: Interesting! I'll try this out on my flash out as well when I get time. Thank you.